# Java drawing editor applet

Tags: java, swing, drawing, awt

I'm looking for a Java Applet which allows the user to draw rectangles, resize them, move them etc, similar to svg-edit http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/

It will be for academic non commercial use. Can anyone point me to a good, open source, Java drawing editor applet?

Comment: I have explored Terppaint, GraphPanel and JGraph but I'm surprised to see that there is no cool applet which can do the job as good as svg-edit. Thinking of adding a bounty to this question...

Comment: Does it have to be an applet?

Comment: how did you get on?  Was one of our answers satisfactory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best applet I know of, with source available, is draw4free.

- [Applet](http://www.draw4free.com/drawPage.htm)
- [Website](http://www.draw4free.com/morePage.htm)
- [Source code](http://www.draw4free.com/sourcePage.htm)

If you are looking for inspiration, there's a few [listed here](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Java/Applets/Graphics_and_Animation/) but most don't have the source available.

If you are less fussed about it being an applet, there's a list of [those too](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Java/Applications/Graphics/) (most with source) and you could also check out:

- [jHotDraw](http://www.jhotdraw.org/) which is based on a formerly commercial project
- [JDraw](http://jdraw.sourceforge.net/) and [Pixelitor](http://pixelitor.sourceforge.net/), although they are about editing bitmaps rather than shapes
- [Sketcher](http://sketcher.sourceforge.net/) (discontinued)
- The imaginatively titled ["draw"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/draw/) which looks like a very simple option

There's loads of examples out there.  I got some of this by searching Sourceforge/Google.

Answer (score 3):

[`GraphPanel`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) is a [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) application, rather than an applet.

Addendum: [`JGraph`](http://www.jgraph.com/) is a more full-featured object drawing environment.

Comment: GraphPanel should be straightforward enough to adapt to being an applet.  (+1 for that, it looks really good, bookmarked!)  JGraph is probably a bit too overwhelming for the needs of the question.

Comment: @Charles: Good point; your excellent [links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565665/java-drawing-editor-applet/6780019#6780019) fill in the middle well. +1 BTW.

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/terppaint/

You can use above open source project built using Java Swing and customize it based on your requirements.

Comment: This appears to be painting program, rather that a vector graphics editor.